# CakePHP and referential integrity

Tags: mysql, cakephp, foreign-keys

My DB server doesn't support innodb engine, so I can't use Foreign key 
costraints at DB level. 
How can I assure referential intergrity? Can I do this using cakephp model, 
how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you define your model associations properly, you should be ok. If you're worried about orphan records when deleting records, you can set `'dependent'=> true` in your associations.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together#hasMany-1043

Answer (score 0):

I'm using myISAM engine on my tables with cakePHP, had no problems so far =).

foreign keys are defined in model like this:

```
// this is a property of Post Model

    var $belongsTo = array(
    'PostCategory' => array(
        'className' => 'PostCategory',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_category_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

this means that current model is associated with PostCategory model using post_category_id column as a foreign key.

Comment: and associating the data has nothing to do with his question.